# Regex To match string starting and ending with characters

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need a regex to perform search in eclipse to match all strings that start with ${ and end with } but should not have pageContext between the two.
For Example

**${requestScope.user}**

**${sessionScope.user}**

should match

but **${pageContext.request}** should not

After all efforts I have made this regex **(\${)** which matches strings starting with **${** but some how doesn't meet my requirement.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead to exclude specific matches:

```
\$\{(?!pageContext\.).*?\}
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!pageContext\.)` lookahead will fail all matches where `{` is followed with `pageContext.`. Also, you can use `[^{}]*` instead of `.*?`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF9gX3/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\$` - a literal `$`
- `\{` - a literal `{`
- `(?!pageContext\.)` - fail the match if a `pageContext.` follows the `{` immediately
- `.*?` - any 0+ characters other than a newline (or `[^{}]*` - zero or more characters other than `{` and `}`)
- `\}` -  a literal `}`.

**NOTE**:

If you need to avoid matching any `${...}` substring with `pageContext.` *anywhere* inside it, use

```
\$\{(?![^{}]*pageContext\.)[^{}]*\}
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, the `[^{}]*` inside the lookahead will look for `pageContext.` after any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, but it is selecting the entire string, what if I just want to select ${ and } with the above condition no the entire string

Comment: @Mckenzie This regex actually doesn't match anything, meaning whatever you're running it through is returning you the string matched, depending upon how your regex is being used adding a capture may and may not do anything, but you *can* capture the match by doing this: `(\$\{(?!pageContext\.).*?\})`

Comment: @Mckenzie: While it is possible to match `${` not followed with `pageContext` with `\$\{(?!pageContext\.)`, it is not possible to use Eclipse regex engine to match `}` that is not preceded with `{pageContext.` since it does not support infinite-width lookbehind.

Comment: FYI: the fastest solution is [`\$\{(?!pageContext\.)[^{}]*\}`](https://regex101.com/r/jF9gX3/2). Or [`\$\{(?!pageContext\.)[^}]*\}`](https://regex101.com/r/jF9gX3/3) if there can be `{` inside the `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Look aheads or look behinds are expensive. You should prefer the optional match trick:

```
\$\{(?:.*pageContext.*|(.*))\}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/tF5fL0/1)

To avoid confusion let me specify that this will *match* any string with a "${" prefix and a "}" suffix, but if that string contained "pageContext" the 1<sup>st</sup> capture will be empty. **If the 1<sup>st</sup> capture is non-empty you have a string matching your criteria.**

Comment: Its selecting ${pageContext.request} as well, but it shud not

Comment: @Mckenzie As you can see from the live example, it is *not capturing* "${pageContext.request}" this will only *capture* if it is a match. How are you using the results of this regex?

Comment: Well, backtracking is more expensive than any anchored lookahead like mine. 64 steps (mine) (or 30 with the negated character class) vs. 110 (yours) on the same content.

Comment: @Jonathan It is capturing it, I am testing it on http://regexr.com/ pls check, the solution provided by Wiktor works

Comment: @Mckenzie If you look in the "List" tab it shows you the captures and corresponding inputs. It's important to note that mine will *match* every line with the "${" prefix and "}" suffix, but the capture will be empty in the case that "pageContext" was found between the braces: http://regexr.com/3du31

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure how you're counting those steps, but we're also not comparing apples to apples here. The OP's request was that the line "should not have pageContext between the two". Your regex matches/captures: "${ pageContext.request}" mine obviously matches but captures nothing.

Comment: The example is clearer than a million of words: OP wants to avoid matching `{}` that has `pageContext` right after `{`. Anyway, your answer does not meet the specifications outlined in your previous comment. I updated my answer to account for that scenario.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As in, you think that mine will capture "${ pageContext.request}"? [Yours](https://regex101.com/r/kM1dK5/1) [Mine](https://regex101.com/r/tV3qU5/1) Maybe you can edit to show me what you're saying? (I did take the OP to mean what he wrote since that was more demanding than the example, and I mean we're all in agreement that your regex correctly handles the example.)

Comment: See the question: *should match ... should not*. Why speak about *capturing* at all? Your regex *matches* all the `{...}`!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew A fair point. I'm only interested in the capture return, which depending upon your regex variant looking at the capture result rather than simply testing for a match may be more of a hassle. (I concur that your edited regex fully solves the problem, with no requirement for testing captures +1) I was simply presenting the alternative that I would have used personally.

Comment: Ok. If I were doung this, I'd use .NET regex based editor and use an infinite width lookbehind to do precisely what is necessary.